# How do you render a component presentation using XSLT page template in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, xslt

I have created a XSLT TBB, which I am using on a page template, and i`m looping over the component presentations, but in the documentation I cant see a function to render the individual component presentations.

In the DWT templates I noticed there is a function called RenderComponentPresentation() but can`t see the equivelent in XSLT documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-69A67594-A1E7-45AA-9401-84E24FBED74B

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate.Title='Article'" -->
    @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Bjorn's answer seems hypothetical, it is almost completely correct. :-)

In general, so-called templating function sources (.NET classes which are exposing their methods to modular templates) are exposed in the XSLT mediator as extension functions in XML namespaces named as:

```
http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/FunctionSource/<FunctionSourceClassName>
```

This applies to built-in functions, other configured function sources and function sources which are implemented in a .NET TBB referenced by the XsltMediator Processing Instruction.

RenderComponentPresentation is a built-in function which is in the "BuiltInFunctions" function source, so the XML namespace is:

```
http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/FunctionSource/BuiltInFunctions
```

Comment: That is a very useful piece of knowledge indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Are these documented anywhere?

This is working well now BTW, except that I can`t get rid of the <tcdl:ComponentPresentation tags , i have tried adding the following "exclude-result-prefixes="xlink tcm msxsl script Builtin tcdl" but with no luck

Answer (score 2):

You will need to invoke the (globally available) function RenderComponentPresentation as explained [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-69A67594-A1E7-45AA-9401-84E24FBED74B#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-0F0B0460-38C4-402A-AFE4-417253BE53BA.xml&docid=GUID-0F0B0460-38C4-402A-AFE4-417253BE53BA&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0F0B0460-38C4-402A-AFE4-417253BE53BA).

The builtin functions are found in Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.BuiltInFunctions but I have no idea if SDL attributed them with an XSLT namespace...

Assuming they did and that namespace was "http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/BuiltinFunctions"
you would declare an XML namespace on your stylesheet like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:Builtin="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/BuiltinFunctions">
```

and call the RenderComponentPresentation builtin function via

```
<xsl:value-of select="Builtin:RenderComponentPresentation($componentId,$templateId)" />
```

If they did not you will have to create your own assembly, put it in a TBB; load the TBB into the XSLT via

```
<?XsltMediator extensionsTbbId="tcm:193-34-2048"?>
```

at the top of your XSLT TBB.

Your assembly would just be passthrough functions for the builtin functions but the class would have the XSLT namespace attribute wired up as below:

```
[XsltExtension(Namespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/BuiltinFunctions")]
public class BuiltinFunctionsXsltExposer : IFunctionSource
```

Give your functions the same name as the builtin functions and it should work.

**Update:
Thanks to Rick who has confirmed that builtin functions are available in XSLT if you use the right namespace declaration the following code should be correct:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:Builtin="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/FunctionSource/BuiltInFunctions">
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="Builtin:RenderComponentPresentation('tcm:5-267','tcm:5-261-32')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will need to pass in valid TCMIDs of the component and template of course!

Comment: I`m getting the following error
Debugging was started in process 'TcmTemplateDebugHost' with id 3468

Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/BuiltinFunctions'.